# jQuery works on only certain id tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

this is my html and my script as well. i know this is all really messy code so i apologize for that as i'm still learning. I would really appreciate some help with this issue. Thanks in advance

```
     <html>

    <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="home.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){


$("#home" ).hover(
    function(){

        $(this).addClass("active");

    },
    function(){
        $(this).removeClass("active");

    }
  );
$("#circle" ).hover(
    function(){

        $(this).addClass("active");

    },
    function(){
        $(this).removeClass("active");

    }
  );
});
  </script>

</head>

<body>

<p class="header"></p>
<p id="yellow"></p>
<p id="circle"></p>
<p id="body"></p>
<p id="body2"></p>
<p id ="logo"></p>
<p id="wood"></p>
<p id ="body3"></p>
<p id ="getintouch"></p>
<div >
<p id ="home">HOME</p>
<p id ="about">ABOUT</p>
<p id="contact">CONTACT</p>
</div>
<p id="circle1" class="circle"></p>
<p id="circle2" class="circle"></p>
<p id="circle3" class="circle"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

and this is my css

```
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
@font-face { font-family: Basic; src: url('fonts/basictitlefont.ttf'); }

 .header{
    position:realtive;
    display: block;
    width:100%;
    min-height: 100px;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
     background-image: url(images/creamconcrete.png);

}
#yellow{
    position:realtive;
    display: block;
    width:100%;
    min-height: 15px;
    background-color: ffa407;
    padding:0px;
   margin:0px;
z-index: 11;

}
#circle{
    background-image: url(images/Counter.png);
    background-size: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 500px;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    margin:0px;
    top:0px;


}

#body{
    position:realtive;
    display: block;
    width:100%;
    min-height: 500px;
    background-color: white;
    padding:0px;

    margin:0px;

}
#body2{
    position:realtive;
    display: block;
    width:100%;
    min-height: 500px;
    background-color: 494949;
    padding:0px;

    margin:0px;

}
#body3{
    position:realtive;
    display: block;
    width:100%;
    min-height: 200px;
    background-color: white;
    padding:0px;

    margin:0px;

}
#logo{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;

    top:60px;
    left:90%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color:6d6c6c;
    position:absolute;

}
#wood{
    background-image: url(images/woodshop.png);
    background-size: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 500px;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    margin:0px;
    top:0px;



}
#getintouch{
    width:500px;
    height:200px;
    top: 1760px;
    position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translatex(-50%);

    border:solid 8px #6d6c6c;

}
#home{
    font-family: Basic;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color:#6d6c6c;
    position: absolute;

    top:40px;
    left:10px;
}
#about{
    font-family: Basic;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color:#ffa407;
    position: absolute;

    top:40px;
    left:200px;
}
#contact{
    font-family: Basic;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color:#ffa407;
    position: absolute;

    top:40px;
    left:400px;
}
#logo{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;

    top:60px;
    left:90%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color:6d6c6c;
    position:absolute;

}
#circle1{
    width:250px;
    height:250px;
    opacity:0.7;
    top:225px;
    left: 50%;
  transform: translatex(-50%);

    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color:ded7c9;
    position:absolute;


}
#circle2{
    width:250px;
    height:250px;
    opacity:0.7;
    top:225px;
    left:70%;

    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color:ded7c9;
    position:absolute;


}
#circle3{
    opacity:0.7;
    width:250px;
    height:250px;

    top:225px;
    left:10%;

    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color:ded7c9;
    position:absolute;


}

.highlighted {
    background-color:#556677;
}
.active{
    background-color: red;

}
```

This is probably a simple issue, but why does my script only run in the section for the id of home and not in the id of circle. I'm applying the same code and class to both but when i hover over my circle it doesn't change. whyyyyy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you talking about `#circle` specifically, or the other circle elements? If you're expecting this to work on `#circle1`, `2`, and `3`, it won't. You've added a class to those circle elements, so you'll need use a class selector instead.

```
$(".circle" ).hover( ... );
```

You'll also need to be aware of CSS specificity. Your `.active` selector will need to be at least as specific, if not more specific, in order for it to take effect. For example:

```
.active, #circle1.active, #circle2.active, #circle3.active {
  background-color: red;
}
```

This is a pretty poor solution, which is why many people recommend avoiding the use of IDs and just using classes. If you switch those IDs to classes, you won't have to modify your `.active` selector. For example:

```
<p class="circle circle1"></p>
<p class="circle circle2"></p>
<p class="circle circle3"></p>
```

Then the CSS:

```
.circle1 { background-color: #ded7c9; }
.circle2 { background-color: #ded7c9; }
.circle3 { background-color: #ded7c9; }

.active { background-color: red; }
```

You can read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Also, if you aren't performing any logic on hover, then you don't need javascript. Just use the `:hover` pseudoclass in your CSS.

Answer (score 0):

your active class Should Be like This

.active{
    background-color: red !important;

}

The Background color of #circle is already applied to the Circle object
so Giving An !important declaration provides a way for a stylesheet author to give a CSS value more weight than it naturally has.

Comment: `!important` should only be used when it's not possible to solve the problem in any other way. Which is extremely rare. Plastering `!important` all over the place is a very lazy way of writing CSS.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be that you are not overwriting the background image. So you simply can't see the background color if the background graphic doesn't have any transparent parts,

```
.active{
    background-color: red !important;
    background-image: none !important;
}
```